# check how often value of array consecutively appears

Tags: c++, arrays, boolean

i have a string "param", say :

param = aaaa;

and i have an array "word" which consists of :

word = [aaaa,aabb,aacc,aaaa,cccc,bbbb,ccdd,ccbb,ddcc,ccee,aaaa];

and i want to check how often another string than param appears on word. from that example above, i expects result to be :
2
6

how do i check that false string consecutively?
i tried to implement some code like this :

```
bool check(std::string param, std::vector< std::string > word)
{
    int sum = 0; //sums of consecutive false string

    for (unsigned int limit =0;limit<word.size();limit++)
    {
        if (word[limit]!=param)
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sum = sum - 1;
        }

    }

    if (sum>=10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

input

```
param : "aaaa"

word : ["aaaa", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "bbbb", 
        "aaaa"]
```

output ==>  false

expected output ==> true

Comment: `limit<=word.size()` should be `limit<word.size()`, otherwise you are reading from the vector out of bounds.

Comment: I wonder why. You'll also need additional `max_sum` variable and to not set `sum` to `0` unconditionally each iteration.

Comment: Are you looking for the overall number of strings != param (8 in your example), the maximum number of consecutives (6 in your example) or all numbers of consecutives ({2,8} in your example)?

Comment: @Anedar , i am looking for each consecutive param!=word. from the example above, it should return {2,6}

Comment: @MuhammadWaqiAzizi You are actually returning a `bool`, I have no clue what you're asking about. Post a [MCVE] please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, the code above is the complete example. bool return value get from the sum of consecutives value of param != word. says if the sums of consecutive value more than or same as 10, it returns true

Comment: @MuhammadWaqiAzizi It's not. Read the link.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqiAzizi Read the link. Edit your question accordingly please. You should provide a minimal but complete program that reproduces the behavior. Show actual input and expected output. Debug before asking.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ i've edited my question. i tried debug the first code into this one, bool return value still false

Comment: @MuhammadWaqiAzizi _"bool return value still false"_ Sure, because the final `sum` is `8`. You subtract `1` for every match with `param`, so why do you actually expect `sum` is `10` for your test case . That could have been found easily when using the debugger as I've been recommending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer. thanks to @πάντα ῥεῖ and @Anedar

here is the right code :

```
bool check(std::string param, std::vector< std::string > word)
{
    int sum = 0; //sums of consecutive false string
    std:vector<int> sums; //array of sum value

    for (unsigned int limit =0;limit<word.size();limit++)
    {
        if (word[limit]!=param)
        {
            ++sum;
        }
        else if (sum!=0)
        {
            sums.push_back(sum);
            sum = 0;
        }

    }

    if (sum!=0)
    {
        sums.push_back(sum); //make sure even if word vector does not end with param, the number still get pushed to counter vector
    }

    int temp = 0; //variable to store maximum value of consecutive array
    for (int iter = 0; iter < sums.size(); iter ++)
    {
        if (sums[iter]>temp)
            temp = sums[iter]; //store maximum value of consecutive array
    }

    //now the return bool value
    if (temp>=10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all, you resetted your sum every loop, so the only two possible results you can get after your for-loop are 1 and -1. What you really want to do when checking consecutives is to reset it only when your current streak has finished, so what you need is something like this:

```
bool check(std::string param, std::vector< std::string > word)
{
    int current=0; //current sum of consecutive false string
    std::vector<int> sums; //finished consecutives are stored here

    for (unsigned int limit =0;limit<word.size();limit++)
    {
        if (word[limit]!=param)
        {
            ++current; 
        }
        else if (current != 0)
        {
            //a consecutive run has just finished
            sums.push_back(current);
            current=0;
        }

    }

    if (current != 0)
        sums.push_back(current);

    //deal with sums here
}
```

I think what it does is pretty straightforward: Count the current strings != param and if it finds a param push the length of the current streak to a vector. You then need to deal with this vector in some way, either by returning it (then bool is the wrong return type) or by doing some other checks with it.

Oh and a small edit: the last if makes sure that even if your vector does not end with a param the number gets pushed to your vector.

Comment: thanks for your help!
your answer help me to realize that i've to store that consecutive value for later bool check

Answer (score 0):

> expected output ==> true

Just remove the subtraction in the `else` part inside the `for()` loop to get the expected output:

```
bool check(std::string param, std::vector< std::string > word)
{
    int sum = 0; //sums of consecutive false string

    for (unsigned int limit =0;limit<word.size();limit++)
    {
        if (word[limit]!=param)
        {
            sum = sum + 1;
        }
        // else
        // {
        //     sum = sum - 1;
        // }

    }

    if (sum>=10)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Heraclitus folks! your answer and Anedar helps me got it through